# CasperJS waitFor*() has very unclear behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to understand how CasperJS work in order to use it on my tests. What i try to accomplish is to take a screenshot of some element of the page when they are ready and fully loaded, i'm using [Whatsapp Web](http://web.whatsapp.com) as an example cause it have the loading i'm looking for.

This is my implementation:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  remoteScripts:  [
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.js'
  ],
  pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36'
  },
  viewport: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 1024
  },
  waitTimeout: 60000,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  verbose: true
});

casper.start('https://web.whatsapp.com/', function(){
    this.echo('Starting...')
    this.waitForSelector('.qrcode', function() {
        this.captureSelector('whatsapp.png', 'html');
        this.echo('Screeshot Taken!')
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Seems that CasperJS will not find `<div class="qrcode"></div>`into the page in 60s, that is quite long time.
What i'm missing here? What waitFor*() is suppose to do?

INFO: PhantomJS v2.0.0

NOTE: what i can tell, is actually that looks like that `waitForSelector()` works async, and i'm wondering why a wait() function have to be implemented like that, what i expect is something like a watcher (or a infinite loop) that will continuously fetch the DOM and check the element with that selector in a certain amount of time.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.x is known to hide some errors, so you should also try 1.9.8.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you taken a screenshot after waiting a bit to see if the page at least loads? Why are you loading remote scripts? Such an old version of jQuery may be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ArtjomB. i so stucked with this. I will upgrade my question with the information you asked for and i try to downgrade to 1.9.8, i was loading remotes scripts just because was faster, fix that as well, i let you know if it solve.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you was right, there was an hided error,  `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'r.bind(this)') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it!
It was a version issue just avoid using `brew` to install `PhantomJS` nor `CasperJS`

What i did was actually:

- `brew uninstall phantomjs && brew uninstall casperjs`
- `npm i -g phantomjs && npm i -g casperjs`

And now my code work as expected.
This bug is actually related to v1.9.8 of PhantomJS, that will trigger this error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

If you are on OSX, reinstall using npm and will work just fine.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Are you able to capture QR code now ? facing **missing=cryptoSha256,cryptoAesCbc**

Comment: @snofty i don't actually know if something change, at the time of my tests yes: https://github.com/nerder/whosup/blob/master/whosapp.js

This was the final code (sorry for the quality was just4fun)